# How to stop this object from overlapping tile's corners in 2D tilemap

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, tilemap

I am using a tilemap to create my 2D world. All tiles and the player has an AABB. Currently, I'm detecting collisions with surrounding tiles the player is in, from the player's center. This works, but when the player's center is outside the tile and another point of the player is still in the previous tile, the wrong tile is getting checked and the player overlaps the corner of the tile getting checked previously.

How can I solve this?

This is my *TypeScript* code:

```
public checkAABB(ent: Entity): TileMap {

    let tileX = this.pxToTile(ent.bounds.centerX());
    let tileY = this.pxToTile(ent.bounds.centerY());

    let indices = [
        [0, -1],
        [1, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [-1, 0]
    ];

    let idx, tile, intersection;

    for (let i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
        idx = indices[i];

        tile = this.getTile((tileX + idx[0]), (tileY + idx[1]));

        intersection = tile.solid && ent.bounds.intersects(tile.bounds);

        if (intersection) {
            this.collisionInfo[i].tile = tile;

            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    this.collisionInfo[i].penetration =   Math.abs(ent.bounds.min().y - tile.bounds.max().y);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.collisionInfo[i].penetration = Math.abs(tile.bounds.min().x - ent.bounds.max().x);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.collisionInfo[i].penetration = Math.abs(ent.bounds.max().y - tile.bounds.min().y);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.collisionInfo[i].penetration = Math.abs(ent.bounds.min().x - tile.bounds.max().x);
                    break;
            }

        }

        this.collisionInfo[i].active = intersection;
    }

    return this;
}
```

Visualization:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried swept AABB?

Comment: I have heard of it, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: https://www.gamedev.net/resources/_/technical/game-programming/swept-aabb-collision-detection-and-response-r3084

Comment: Typically you don't do centerofobject based checks for AABB objects if they are all AABB. You usually check based off the corners of the rectangles/tiles.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved this issue by checking all surrounding tiles of the player, by using the max possible overlap integer in a loop. The problem now is that it detects the collision too late. The player has already penetrated the tile and on the next frame it gets corrected. How do I solve this?

Comment: I don't know your language but the concept would be to run the collision detection with a "future value" and if it collides with that value, don't move the object there, if it doesn't collide with that future value, apply the movement. Alternatively you could move the object, check collision, if collide, correct it back, and only then end the game loop and update the screen. You see, I'm guessing your problem is you are checking collision before moving the object. Instead, move, check, resolve, update. Or. Check with future value, move or don't move based on result, update screen.

Comment: Thanks Neal, I solved it by comparing your sequence to mine. My sequence was wrong indeed.

Comment: @M.T. Easy mistake to make.